# How to get first two characters of a string in oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a column name `OrderNo` with value `AO025631` in a table `shipment`.

I am trying to query the table so that I can get only first two character of column value i.e. `AO`.

Can I do this in the SQL query itself?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

***SUBSTR*** [(documentation)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(OrderNo, 1, 2) As NewColumnName from shipment
```

When selected, it's like any other column. You should give it a name (with `As` keyword), and you can selected other columns in the same statement:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(OrderNo, 1, 2) As NewColumnName, column2, ... from shipment
```

Comment: would you please explain what is 1 and 2? is it starting and ending index?

Comment: The second arg is the starting index, which is 1 based (i.e. 1 is the first character, 2 is the second). The third argument is the number of characters to substring from that index, in your case you want the first two.

Comment: `SUBSTR` = substring. `Arg1` = columnName, `Arg2`: The position at which the first character of the returned string begins. `Arg3`: The length of the returned string. So in your case, you want to start from the begninning of `AO025631` => `Arg2 = 1` and you want 2 characters => `Arg3 = 2`. *follow the link in my response for more explanation*

Comment: thanks to both of you..i am confuse which answer i should select because all came simultaneously.. :)

Comment: @manji- one more question if i want to do this in query it self then how to go? mymean is i want to select some more column of the table but only first two char of orderNo column, then how can i write select statement for this.

Comment: See my edit. I recommend that you read some quick documentations/tutorials about basic `SQL` concepts because it's impotant that you know that.

Comment: ya..that's want i want..yeah definately i will go through some tutorial... thanks a lot.

Comment: it's funny how substr works, when you use it in php the starting position is 0 but when you use it in sql the starting position is 1... how cool is that !!!

Answer (score 18):

```
select substr(orderno,1,2) from shipment;
```

You may want to have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html#GUID-C8A20B57-C647-4649-A379-8651AA97187E) too.

Answer (score 11):

take a look [here](http://psoug.org/reference/substr_instr.html)

```
SELECT SUBSTR('Take the first four characters', 1, 4) FIRST_FOUR FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 10):

Easy:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(OrderNo, 1, 2) FROM shipment;
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use [SUBSTR](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) function. It takes 3 parameters: String column name, starting index and length of substring:

```
select SUBSTR(OrderNo, 1, 2) FROM shipment;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try select substr(orderno, 1,2) from shipment;